# One word describing a money transfer to a digital wallet

Tags: single-word-requests, technology, finance

I'm wondering how to describe in one word (a noun) the act of transferring money from a lottery operator to the digital wallet of a player who won a prize.

It's supposed to be the name of a wallet operation (along with *deposit*, *withdrawal* and *payment*) shown to the player in the mobile application.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't it a "deposit"?

Comment: @terdon In our nomenclature a _deposit_ is a transfer of money from a player to their own wallet. We need a different word to distinguish these two operations.

Answer (score 1):

As you are specifically referring to prizes you could use the word [payout](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/payout). It sounds informal but is widely used and only refers to a payment from an organisation to an individual.

If all payouts are made using the digital wallet then 'payout' on its own would be sufficient, otherwise a term such as 'digital payout' or 'wallet payout' would distinguish such transactions from 'cheque payouts', 'PayPal payouts' or other types of payout transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with *[award](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/award)*.

> An amount of money given as an official payment, compensation, or grant.
>   ‘a 1.5 per cent pay award’

Answer (score 0):

[1. Disbursement](https://www.wordnik.com/words/disbursement)

> disbursement (dĭs-bûrsˈmənt)►
>
> ```
> n.
> The act or process of disbursing.
> n.
> Money paid out; expenditure.
> ```

2. Winnings

[3.Payout](https://www.wordnik.com/words/payout)

Answer (score 0):

***Cash-in***: As in "cash in" one's chips for legal tender at a casino, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want a word for the operation performed by the *payer* on a *wallet* owned and controlled by the receiver.  Regardless of the technology involved, the word choice is inherently difficult, since the payer does not actually *control* the wallet, e.g. they can't withdraw a payment once made.  Your term should reflect this lesser capability and the one-way nature of the transaction.  Some possibilities include:

- credit,
- present payment to,
- update,
- augment,
- load,
- supply.